# Mongo query to return distinct count, large documents

Tags: mongodb

I need to be able to get a count of distinct 'transactions' the problem I'm having is that using .distinct() comes back with an error because the documents too large.

I'm not familiar with aggregation either.

I need to be able to group it by 'agencyID' as you see below there are 2 different agencyID's

[image]

[image]

I need to be able to count `transactions` where the agencyID is `01721487` etc

```
db.myCollection.distinct("bookings.transactions").length
```

this doesn't work as I need to be able to group by agencyID and if there are too many results I get an error saying it's too large.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5624a610a6e6b53b158b4744"),
    "agencyID" : "01721487",
    "paxID" : "-530189664",
    "bookings" : [ 
        {
            "bookingID" : "24232",
            "transactions" : [ 
                {
                    "tranID" : "001",
                    "invoices" : [ 
                        {
                            "invNum" : "1312",
                            "type" : "r",
                            "inv_date" : "20150723",
                            "inv_time" : "0953",
                            "inv_val" : -300
                        }
                    ],
                    "tranType" : "Fee",
                    "tranDate" : "20150723",
                    "tranTime" : "0952",
                    "opCode" : "admin",
                    "udf_1" : "j s"
                }
            ],
            "acctID" : "acct11",
            "agt_id" : "xy"
        }
    ],
    "title" : "",
    "firstname" : "",
    "surname" : "f bar"
}
```

[I've also tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929411/mongo-query-to-sort-by-distinct-count) but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932924/how-to-solve-mongodb-related-issue-efficiently) and please add some stuff to your qestion. Thank you.

Comment: @profesor79 Can't see anything different from the examples in that and my post.

Comment: cannot paste screenshot in to editor :-)

Comment: @profesor79 it is a screenshot because I have sensitive information. The documents are a lot larger than shown

Comment: it takes a few seconds to scrub data :-) and get result from first shot just use F5 (to execute query) then F4 (to display in text) in robomongo. btw what's wrong with aggregation example that you provided?

Comment: @profesor79 I've added it in, the only difference with the screenshots is the agencyID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for text data -
this is something you could play with:

```
db.kieron.aggregate([{
            $unwind : "$bookings"
        }, {
            $match : {
                "bookings.transactions" : {
                    $exists : true,
                    $not : {
                        $size : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group : {
                _id : "$agencyID",
                count : {
                    $sum : {
                        $size : "$bookings.transactions"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

as there is nested array we need to unwind it first, and then we can check size of inner array.

Happy reporting!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got this error `"errmsg" : "exception: The argument to $size must be an Array, but was of type: EOO",`

Comment: are there empty transactions arrays ?

Comment: @Kieron606 added exculding  `$match` to eliminate empty and null arrays

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, is there a way I can search between a range of dates? show transaction count where tranDate => '20160501' and <= '20160601'

Comment: @Kieron606 `$match`   is your friend

Comment: Yeah, I managed to get it working with `"bookings.transactions.tranDate":"20140226"` but as I have my dates custom, how can i match in between for example 20140226 and 20150226